# CoreData relationship save issue

Tags: ios, core-data

i have two tables in core data, say table TA and table TB, TA has one-to-many relationships with TB.
There is one record A1 in TA, and i'd like to have several records(B1,B2,..) in TB mapping to A1 in the for loop.
In first iteration, i query db and get A1, invoke addTBObject:B1 and didn't save the context.
In next iteration, query again to get A1, but it return nil. (So strange...)

If i save the context in the first interation, then it's ok to get A1 again in the next iteration. But i don't think this is a better practice, which would result many save actions in one for loop.

Can anybody help on this? Appreciate on that!

code extract:

```
NSString* objBId = @"xxx";
for (int i=0; i< [dataArray count]; i++) {
    ObjA obj = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSManagedObject* moObjA = [self getManagedObjAById:obj.objId inContext:context];
    if(moObjA)
    {
        NSManagedObject* moObjB = [self getManagedObjBById:objBId inContext:context];
        if (moObjB != nil)
        {
            [moObjB addAObject:moObjA];
            [self saveDB:context]; //if don't save here, moObjB will be nil in the next iteration...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: just updated, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure getManagedObj_ById is implemented correctly? Also check if your relationship is correctly setup as to-many. Other than that, I can't see anything suspicious.

Comment: So the saveDB could be placed after the for loop complete if everything is set up correctly?

Comment: Sure. Why are you even adding the objects in an inner loop instead of grabbing a set and adding them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Seems found the clue to this problem.
In the implementation of getManagedObjBById, the NSFetchRequest is initiated each time, if there is no commit in each iteration, the fetch request will return nil in next iteration.

After I changed the code to use [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TabelB"], it's all set! The for loop can always get the managed object B in each iteration without save any more.

Looking further, does this mean the NSFetchRequest for certain entity can only be initialized once before commit (one transaction)??

origin code:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"xxx" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
```

Now:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"xxx"];
```